# How to change WEBrick :AccessLog option when running RedMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, webrick

I'm running RedMine via WEBrick using the following command line (simplified):

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -p 3012 -P '/var/lib/redmine/redmine.pid'
```

I don't like how WEBrick outputs the peer address at the beginning of its access log lines (because I'm running it behind nginx and the peer address is always 127.0.0.1), so I want to change the access log format.

I know that I need to tune the `:AccessLog` config option for WEBrick, but I don't know how to get my hands on it. WEBrick is run by the `rails server` command, via the `rack` abstraction, and I don't see an obvious way to pass the necessary configuration to WEBrick.

So, is there any way to do it? Some command line switch? `-c` is the only switch that accepts some kind of configuration file, but it references "rackup", and I have no idea how to work with it.

Maybe it can be done by changing configuration files? I tried to modify `additional_environment.rb` by adding `config[:AccessLog] = [ [ $stderr, WEBrick::AccessLog::COMMON_LOG_FORMAT ] ]`, but it had no effect (although the file was executed), so I assume this file's `config` is not what is passed to WEBrick.

I'm pretty sure there is some way to configure this option *without* creating a new Rails application and invoking WEBrick manually, and hopefully even without changing RedMine files.

Comment: Have you ever considered running Redmine via puma actually? Just add gem 'puma', and I thin it should work.

Comment: @AleksandarPavić It's not that easy because I'm running Redmine via NixOS's module, which makes such customizations quite cumbersome, and non-trivial to maintain. Why would I want to use puma? Does it have better configurability? Does it use X-Real-IP in its access logs without additional configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this hits your question, I have no idea of RedMine.

But:

With Rails you can access webrick with:

```
::WEBrick::Config::HTTP[:AccessLog] #leading :: depend on installation
```

I put this line in my application.rb

```
WEBrick::Config::HTTP[:AccessLog]=[[STDOUT, format_in_accesslog.rb ]]
```

like

```
WEBrick::Config::HTTP[:AccessLog]=[[Logger.new(STDOUT), "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"]]
```

in `accesslog.rb` you find

```
# This format specification is a subset of mod_log_config of Apache:
#
# %a:: Remote IP address
# %b:: Total response size
# %e{variable}:: Given variable in ENV
# %f:: Response filename
# %h:: Remote host name
# %{header}i:: Given request header
# %l:: Remote logname, always "-"
# %m:: Request method
# %{attr}n:: Given request attribute from <tt>req.attributes</tt>
# %{header}o:: Given response header
# %p:: Server's request port
# %{format}p:: The canonical port of the server serving the request or the
#              actual port or the client's actual port.  Valid formats are
#              canonical, local or remote.
# %q:: Request query string
# %r:: First line of the request
# %s:: Request status
# %t:: Time the request was received
# %T:: Time taken to process the request
# %u:: Remote user from auth
# %U:: Unparsed URI
# %%:: Literal %
```

The syntax is `[[out, format],[out, format]]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to configure logging by using your code with some additions. I'll describe it in my own, Redmine-specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [halfbit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77269787/3088208), but it's specific to Redmine.

The `:AccessLog` config option for WEBrick (which I mentioned in the question) can be accessed from Redmine's `additional_environment.rb` configuration file (which is `instance_eval`'ed from Redmine's `application.rb`) via the expression `WEBrick::Config::HTTP[:AccessLog]`; however, it will not work until `webrick` is imported.

Here is what my configuration (put into `additional_environment.rb`) now looks like:

```
require 'webrick'
ourAccessLogger = Logger.new('/var/lib/redmine/log/access.log')
WEBrick::Config::HTTP[:AccessLog] = [
  [ ourAccessLogger, '%{X-Real-IP}i %l %u %t "%r" %s %b' ],
  [ ourAccessLogger, WEBrick::AccessLog::REFERER_LOG_FORMAT ]
]
```

A simpler configuration, the one I tried to use in the question, would be applied like this:

```
require 'webrick'
WEBrick::Config::HTTP[:AccessLog] = [ [ $stderr, WEBrick::AccessLog::COMMON_LOG_FORMAT ] ]
```